# Vision API - Product Search – detectable category tree

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, vision-api, google-product-search

I am looking for some help with finding a list of categories recognized by Google Vision API either by Object Localizer API or by Product Search API.

I searched the issue and found an old post here https://groups.google.com/g/cloud-vision-discuss/c/Gpo2h-Rw7gA/m/uSHH-r8lAgAJ and linked StackOverflow questions.
However, after a thorough examination of Open Images V6 and Google Knowledge Graph, I still do not see a clear connection between Open Images category tree and Vision API Product Search.

Product Search API has 5 main productCategories: homegoods, apparel, toys, packedgoods, general. (link: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/product-categories)

However, Open Images does not have any of these categories https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/2018_04/bbox_labels_600_hierarchy_visualizer/circle.html.

Can anyone help me with a list of detailed categories returned by a detector in Product Search and corresponding top-category (homegoods, apparel, toys, packedgoods, general)?
I would like what categories can be detected in each of the top-category, so for example: "Apparel": ["Pants", "Skirt", "Shoes", ...].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? As you have mentioned that in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/product-categories), the product categories and its sub categories are provided in the description. Products coming under a certain product category depends on the product set you are using.

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I want to know what products exactly are included in each product category from the documentation. It is needed for the implementation and proper filtration of results. I am quite surprised that such a list is not publicly available.

Comment: Hi @Bonzogonda, The detailed list of product categories and it’s related products is undocumented. If you want this to be documented or want the information about it, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).